# How do I run a command on each input given a list of input

Tags: scripting, tcsh

I have a bunch of folders, and I want to cd into each folder and run a command. I feel like it should be something like this:

(The following is a contrived and simplified example of what I want to do).

```
ls | xargs echo 'Looking at {}' && cd {} && /bin/do_stuff
```

But that does not work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `xargs` executes its command directly. It does not accept a line of shell code and pass the command to the shell to execute. In fact, all of those `&&`s are being interpreted by the shell *before* `ls` and `xargs` even run. Also, `{}` is a construct that `find` understands, not `xargs`.

(You could use `-I` with `xargs` to mimic that feature of `find`, if you wanted.)

The simplest way to do this with `xargs` is to put your command into a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Looking at $1"
cd $1
/bin/do_stuff
```

(I've effectively replaced your `&&` with `;` since it looks like `echo` and `cd` cannot fail, as long as you run this in a directory that only contains other subdirectories. If you need "and" behavior, the required fix to the script is obvious.)

Then, run that shell script via `xargs`. If you called it `dostuff.sh`:

```
$ ls | xargs ./dostuff.sh
```

`dostuff.sh` needs to be marked executable, as with `chmod +x dostuff.sh`.

There's probably a way to write all that on a single line with `sh -c`, but if you can't remember the magic to do such a thing, it's mostly just a curiosity, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` is the right tool, but it's difficult to use.

`xargs` doesn't run a shell, unless you tell it to. It runs the command given in the first non-option argument, and passes it the other arguments on its command line followed by arguments read from standard input. For example

```
echo hello world | xargs echo 'Looking at'
```

runs `echo 'Looking at' hello world`. To run the command once per input line, use `xargs -L1`:

```
(echo hello; echo world) | xargs -L1 echo 'Looking at'
```

Since you want `xargs` to run a shell command, you need to make it invoke a shell explicitly.

```
(echo hello; echo world) | xargs sh -c 'echo "Looking at $0" && cd "$0" && /bin/do_stuff'
```

(Or `tcsh -c` if you really want, but come one, this is the 21st century.)

You can use `-I {}` to interpolate `{}` inside the command, but beware that this only works if the input doesn't contain any shell special characters. Passing the input as an argument to the command (`$0` above) has the advantage of not making any assumption on the input (beyond being line-separated and not containing trailing whitespace, as per `xargs -L` syntax).

In a Bourne/POSIX-style shell, an alternative approach which uses more lines but is a lot clearer is to use a loop around the `read` shell builtin:

```
{ echo hello; echo world; } |
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "Looking at $line"
  (cd "$line" && /bin/do_stuff)
done
```

(Note that I execute `cd` in a subshell, because the whole loop is executed in the same shell and I don't want to change that shell's working directory.)